# Encountering issues when implementing url previewing in android using jsoup library

Tags: html, jsoup

i am implementing an android application and i'd like to implement an url link preview in it . As a first try , i have used the jsoup library but i am encountering some issues .Not  all the links have metadata or some information are missing like the image , the data or the description .Also , some links are causing some errors like :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Is there another alternative to implement an url preview in android ??

Here is what i have already done :

```
           Utils.getJsoupData(link)
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe({result: Document ->

               // Log the entire HTML content
               Log.d("TAG", "HTML Content: $result")
               val metaTags = result.getElementsByTag("meta")
               for(element in metaTags)
               {
                   when{
                       element.attr("property").equals("og:image")
                               ->{

                           if(element.attr("content")!=null){
                               Picasso.get()
                                   .load(element.attr("content"))
                                   .into(binding.image)
                           }
                           else{
                               binding.imageTitleDescriptionLayout.visibility= View.INVISIBLE
                           }
                               }
                       element.attr("property").equals("og:url")
                               ->{
                                   val browserUri = element.attr("content")
                                    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                           i.data= Uri.parse(browserUri)
                           context.startActivity(i)
                               }
                       element.attr("property").equals("og:title")
                               -> binding.title.text=element.attr("content")
                       element.attr("name").equals("description")
                               ->{
                           if(element.attr("content")!=null){
                               binding.description.text=element.attr("content")
                               Log.d("TAG", "bind: The description text is ...${element.attr("content")} ")
                           }else{
                               binding.imageTitleDescriptionLayout.visibility= View.INVISIBLE
                           }
                           }
                       element.attr("property").equals("og:url")
                       -> {
                           binding.address.text=element.attr("content")

                           Log.d("TAG", "bind: The url text is ...${element.attr("content")} ")

                       }



                   }
               }


           },

               { error -> Toast.makeText(context,error.message+"there is an error ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                   Log.e("TAG", "Error fetching data", error)
               })
```

and here is the getJsoupData function :

```
object Utils {

@JvmStatic
fun getJsoupData(url:String):Observable<Document>{
 return Observable.fromCallable {
     try {
         return@fromCallable Jsoup.connect(url)
             .timeout(0)
             .get()
     }catch(e:IOException)
     {
         throw RuntimeException(e)
     }
 }
}
```

}